# How can I generate the URL for a controller/view, from within a separate controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm generating a large table of data, and would like to have a link to update certain portions of the table. Is there a way I can generate the URL that will redirect to another controller/view from within the controller I'm using?

I have this code:

```
HTMLTable.AppendLine("        <td class=\"team\"> " + tournament.TournamentRoundMatches[col][effective_match_id].competitorId1 + "<a href=\"<% =Html.BuildUrlFromExpression<CompetitionController>(c => c.Details(83)) %>\">" + "  update" + "</a>" + "</td>");
```

But this doesn't render correctly - I've tried several other methods, including creating a temp string just before the html:

```
string temp = Url.Action("Details", "Competition", new { id = 83 }, Request.Url.Scheme);
```

This doesn't work either though - I get an error that an object reference is required for using "Url"

Can someone shed some light on this?  How can I generate the URL for a separate controller from within this controller?  The controller I'm in is called 'TournamentController', and I want to redirect the user to the "Details" view of the 'CompetitionController' when they click 'Update' - is this possible?

Comment: what was the problem with the `string temp` approach ?

Comment: Please post error message and/or stack trace

Comment: Are you generating (html) output within the controller? That seems like a very odd way of doing whatever it is you're trying to do. You should build a view model and let the view generate the output from this model.

Comment: @SteenT : Agree with you. A controller should know nothing about the rendering of the view

Comment: Thanks for the replies - the controller builds an html string that passes back to the view - from there, the html is executed using html.raw(). The error I get with {string temp} is the following:  Error 3 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Url.get'

Is there something I should be including in my file to have access to Url.Action() ?